# Using Bootstrap Datepicker Internationally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, internationalization

I've been building an app that needs to work internationally. In this app, I'm using the [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html). I am able to successfully initializing a date picker using the following:

```
<input id="myDatePicker" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">

$('#myDatePicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  clearBtn: true,
  language: 'zh-CN',
  startDate: '01/01/1900',
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

When a user chooses a date, it correctly gets displayed in Chinese. My problem is, sometimes when the page loads, I need to pre-select the date. If I wanted `myDatePicker` to already be selected to June 1, in Chinese, what value do I need to put in the `value` attribute of the `input` element.

Due to the way the code is structured, I cannot set the value in the `.datepicker` initialization code. I need to set the value in the `value` attribute of the `input` element.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what the docs say [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html) the following format is acceptable:

`"06-01-2012"`

Making your HTML look like so:

```
<input id="myDatePicker" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="06-01-2015">
```